# WP7 - Share Button like Marketplace and Pictures

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there an easy way to create a `Share` button or link in WP7, like in the Marketplace when you click an app, or like when you view Pictures.  I want to be able to share data/link about something in my app ... on Facebook, email, whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why do you not use the connected networks from the OS?

create a button with XAML, for example:

```
<Button Content="share" Grid.Row="1" Name="shareButton" Click="shareButton_Click"/>
```

Something like this for the click event:

```
 private void shareButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var url = String.Format(Your Item here);
        ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
        shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
        shareLinkTask.Title = postTitleTxt.Text;
        shareLinkTask.Message = "Your Text here: " + postTitleTxt.Text;
        shareLinkTask.Show();
     }
```

For Email you can use this:

```
private void sendEmail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmailComposeTask emailAuthor = new EmailComposeTask();
        emailAuthor.To = "whoever@hotmail.com";
        emailAuthor.Subject = "message from my App";
        emailAuthor.Body = "Text";
        emailAuthor.Show();
    }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check ["Launchers and Choosers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769556%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). A Launcher is an API that launches one of the built-in applications like composing an email, sharing a link on a social network, and opening the browser to a specific website